# The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset. The shared data source 'XXX' for the report server or SharePoint site is not valid

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2, olap-cube

My error is below:

```
The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset. 
The shared data source 'XXX' for the report server or SharePoint site is not valid. 
Browse to the server or site and select a shared data source. (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)
```

Right. I've checked all 3 data sources and they connect fine. I've deleted the report and data sources and deployed them again but still the error. I've used Notepad++ to check for the reference `XXX` in any of the files and still nothing.

These options are both checked.

```
Always run this report with the most recent data 
Do not cache temporary copies of this report
```

Under **Snapshot Options > Allow report history to be created manually** I get a warning of `Credentials used to run this report are not stored`. Could this be a reason?

My data sources are setup like:

[image]

I have read other similar posts but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: I assume since you have tagged the question under "mdx", the data source is an analysis services server. And yet - you have set the Data source type to Microsoft SQL Server as per the screenshot. Could that be the issue.

Comment: Sorry no, that was just an example screenshot I found to demonstrate the highlighted area and the checkbox used

Answer (score 1):

A restart of report server resolved this particular issue for some annoyingly odd reason

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Datasets and check the Data Source being used if it's pointing to the correct data source